# IE and Chrome not displaying certain elements on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As you’ll see, on Chrome the slideshow (on the left) doesn’t load, and on IE, the video (on the right) doesn’t load. Can anyone see a reason for this? Firefox loads both elements just fine :(

[My site in question](http://www.wakeup.com.au/sidebar)

Chrome screenshot (slideshow on middle left not displaying)
[image]

IE screenshot (video on bottom right not displaying)
[image]

Comment: It's working in Chrome for me (OSX, version 24.0.1312.57). Obviously can't test IE. :)

Comment: Thanks David. No prob!

Comment: It works on chrome for me too. Except the video. It seems that your video urls return 404.

Comment: Good point! Didn't see that one. Thank you. Now just the slideshow issue..

Answer (score 1):

> SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
>   www.wakeup.com.au, line 1 character 9
>
> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference
>   jquery.min.js, line 29 character 312
>
> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'dispatchEvent'
>   prototype.js, line 6598 character 5
>
> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'flightbox'
>   www.wakeup.com.au, line 526 character 6
>
> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'width' of undefined or null reference 
>   lightbox.js, line 33 character 6

---

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery.min.js:29
>
> - c.extend.each jquery.min.js:29
> - e.widget jquery.ui.widget.min.js:5
> - (anonymous function) jquery.ui.tabs.min.js:5
> - (anonymous function) jquery.ui.tabs.min.js:5
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'dispatchEvent' prototype.js:6598
>
> - fireEvent_DOM prototype.js:6598
> - fire prototype.js:6587
> - _methodized prototype.js:456
> - fireContentLoadedEvent prototype.js:6773
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'flightbox' www.wakeup.com.au:526
>
> - (anonymous function) www.wakeup.com.au:526
> - c.extend.ready jquery.min.js:26
> - L jquery.min.js:33
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of undefined lightbox.js:33
>
> - Object.extend.setWidth lightbox.js:33
> - Lightbox.initialize lightbox.js:113
> - klass prototype.js:80
> - initLightbox lightbox.js:537
> - (anonymous function) prototype.js:6723

You don't supposed these could have anything to do with it, do you?

Comment: Thanks Kolink. They're standard JS libs though? Any idea what is causing the issue though?

Comment: It means you're calling these standard libs with erroneous input, or you're missing some supporting .js files.

Comment: Thanks Kolink. I'll look into it now. Also what addon were you using to grab that data? JS inspection..

Comment: Both. It's a common shortcut.